# $\cos(t)$ as a function of (t-2)?

Tags: trigonometry

As the title suggests,
I'm doing a Laplace transform problem using the $t$-shift theorem, and I've almost got it, I just can't work out how to transform $\cos(t)$ into a function of $(t-2)$, I saw a trig identity

$$\cos(x)\cos(y) = \frac{1}{2} [\cos(x - y) + \cos(x + y)]$$

But I can't quite work out how to re-arrange it, 
any help much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: $\cos(t)=f(t-2)$ if $f(t)=\cos(t+2)$.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks but I'm looking to get f(t) = cos(t) but all terms that include t are in the form (t-2). eg something like; cos(t) = f(t) = A.sin(t-2) + B.cos(t-2)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\cos t = \cos((t-2)+2)$ *is* a function of $t-2$. If you prefer to express it as a linear combination of $\sin (t-2)$ and $\cos (t-2)$, you can indeed use a trig identity:

$\cos (x+y) = \cos x \cos y - \sin x \sin y$ will work (with $x=t-2$ and $y=2$).

Comment: I think I'll need it as a linear combination of sin(t-2) and cos(t-2) , but am confused how to re arrange the above identity. Wouldnt that just become cos(t-2) = cos(t)cos(-2)-sin(t)sin(-2) giving cos(t)=cos(t-2)+sin(t)sin(-2) / cos(-2)? Unsure how to get to the magical cos(t) = Xcos(t-2) + Ysin(t-2).

Comment: @tomatosource, I think the point is to use the identity for $\cos(x+y)$ with $x=t-2$ and $y=2$.

Comment: Aha, gotcha. Thank you very much.